# Modifying a .npy file. ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Tags: python, numpy

We need to modify a .npy file. So we thought:

1. saving it as a text file
2. Modifying it, then
3. converting it back to .npy format

Our code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

    x=np.load("TIMIT_labels.npy", allow_pickle=True)
    p=np.asarray(x)
    j=open('testing.txt','w')
    np.savetxt('testing.txt',p, delimiter =', ')
    j.close
```

We are getting the below error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    np.savetxt('testing.txt',p, delimiter =', ')
  File "/home/iiit_admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1377, in savetxt
    "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead
```

npy file has multiline data in this format, 'TRAIN/DR5/FJXM0/SX311.WAV': 267, 'TRAIN/DR3/FJLR0/SX241.WAV': 123, 'TRAIN/DR5/MEWM0/SI718.WAV': 291,.....

Please suggest how to modify .npy file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post few lines of data from you .npy file

Comment: Make sure you understand what `x` is.  Don't assume anything, even if you know what was originally saved.  The starting point is to check the `shape` and `dtype`.  From the error I suspect it is a scalar array, with shape `()` and object dtype.  What is this `object`?  If the original object was not an array, `np.save` wrapped it in an array in order to save it.  The fact that you had to `allow_pickle` supports this deduction.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi  npy file has data in his format, 'TRAIN/DR5/FJXM0/SX311.WAV': 267, 'TRAIN/DR3/FJLR0/SX241.WAV': 123, 'TRAIN/DR5/MEWM0/SI718.WAV': 291,.....

Comment: @ShruthiSridhar can you add this data lines into you question? Data is in format of single or multiline?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi : We are trying to run  mravanelli/SincNet (https://github.com/mravanelli/SincNet) in github.Here we have a TIMIT_labels.npy file under SincNet/data_lists/. We want to edit the npy file.

Comment: You don't edit the file.  You modify the loaded array , or more likely make a new array from it,  Then save that with `np.save` or `np.savetxt`  We don't what the array is like, or what changes you want..

Comment: I'm guessing the array is a object array containing a dictionary.  `dd=x.item()` might give you the dictionary.  `savetxt` cannot be used in this case.

Comment: You should use a context manager to handle that file object. This program is 6 lines long, you should be able to debug it. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/